# Margins between panels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi this is the code I have pls:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy))+
  geom_point()+ 
  facet_grid( ~ drv) +
  theme(panel.margin = unit(.05, "lines"),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1), 
        strip.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1))
```

I would like to draw a margin between the 3 panels (dotted lines ) and also how can I please remove the 'cty' legend which is appearing on x-axis? Many thanks

Comment: To remove x-axis title use `+ xlab("")`. Can you show your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid( ~ drv) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.background = element_rect(color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line()) +
  annotation_custom(grid::linesGrob(gp = grid::gpar(lty = 2)), 
                    xmin = 7.7, xmax = 7.7)
```

[image]